# xcode 11 - lldb server keeps crashing

Tags: xcode, lldb

I am trying to use the debugger in Xcode, but since I installed version 11.2, it keeps crashing with this message: Message from debugger: The LLDB RPC server has crashed. The crash log is located in ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports and has a prefix 'lldb-rpc-server'. Please file a bug and attach the most recent crash log.

The crash log is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HB0mAWHiBgZRtyuDWRvpdZKPeQlMRnKR/view?usp=sharing

Is there any solution/workaround for this?

Comment: It looks like there has been one or two reports of a crash here, but no one has been able to show a project where it reproduces so it could be debugged.  If you can show this happening in a project you could send in, please file a report with Feedback Assistant https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/welcome